# How do you set up a game loop for SceneKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm trying to use SceneKit for the first time for a game and am wondering what you are supposed to do for a game loop for updating game state.  I'm aware of

```
SCNSceneRendererDelegate.renderer:updateAtTime:
```

but this is not called if there are no changes to the scene and it does not need to be re-rendered.  I also know that you can force rendering by using

```
SCNView.playing = true
```

but it seems wasteful to force a render when it's not necessary, as this is going to be frequent in my game. I could use an `NSTimer`, but then how do you synchronise it with `render:updateAtTime:`?

Answer (score 1):

The Apple documentation for `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` specifically calls out `renderer:updateAtTime:`, `renderer:didApplyAnimationsAtTime:`, and `renderer:didSimulatePhysicsAtTime:` as the places to add custom game loop logic.

Have you measured (with Instruments) a performance or energy difference when `SCNView.playing` is `true`? This sounds like a premature optimization.